# Shared Preference on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, retrofit, sharedpreferences, okhttp

TokenInterceptor.class

```
public OkHttpClient getClients(Context context) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("logged", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String tokens = preferences.getString("token", "");
    return new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                .header("xc-auth", ""+tokens)
                                .build();

                        return chain.proceed(request);

                    }
                })
                .readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .cache(null)
                .build();
    }
```

ApiClient.class

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new TokenInterceptor().getClients();
    if (retrofit == null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient()
                                     .create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))

                    .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
String ResponseJson = response.body().string();
Gson objGson = new Gson();
tokenResponse objResp = objGson.fromJson(ResponseJson, tokenResponse.class);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "успешно:"+ResponseJson, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
token = ResponseJson;
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("logged", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLogged", true);
editor.putString("token", token);
editor.apply();
```

---

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

W/System.err:     at com.example.tokenauth.RestApi.TokenInterceptor.getClients(TokenInterceptor.java:35)

W/System.err:     at com.example.tokenauth.RestApi.ApiClient.getClient(ApiClient.java:26)

W/System.err:     at com.example.tokenauth.MainActivity.CallLoginService(MainActivity.java:58)

W/System.err:     at com.example.tokenauth.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:30)

W/System.err:     at com.example.tokenauth.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
```

Comment: The context is null.

Comment: context.getSharedPreferences is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change into `ApiClient.java` like:

```
public static Retrofit getClient(Context context) {
    OkHttpClient client = new TokenInterceptor().getClients(context);
    ...
}
```

And into `MainActivity.java` like:

```
new ApiClient().getClient(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Is it the same in other classes?